# How to disable back button when open browser using InAppbrowser in Ionic3

Tags: angularjs, ionic3

I am using InAppbrowser component in Ionic3 for the open browser in ionic App. Please suggest me, how to disable hardware android back button when open browser. when I am using custom back handler or this .view.showBackButton(false), it's working perfectly in any ionic page but in not working in the browser.

Comment: https://jordanhollinger.com/2012/06/08/disable-the-back-button-using-html5/